# ¿Cómo llenar un Label con datos de SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net

Estoy desarrollando en C# y quiero llenar un label con información que se encuentra en una base de datos en SQL. stoy intentando esto, pero no lo he logrado, ya que el sistema no reconoce el nombre del label que necesito llenar con la información:

```
 protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.1.1;Initial Catalog=FLX_Utils;User ID=sa;Password=****");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TBL_TR_MNGR_VCCNS_Usuarios", cnx);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.fill(dt);
        lblFechaIngreso.text = dt.Rows["FechaIngreso"];

    }
```

Comment: ¿Recibes algún error en concreto al ejecutar el programa? (si sí, ¿en qué línea de código y cuál?)

Comment: Con respecto a que no reconoce el nombre del label, intenta agregar otra label y no cambies el nombre, intenta declararla en tu query y comentas que pasa.

Comment: No compartas informacion de tu conexion

Comment: Dudo que pueda llenar la properidad .Text con un objecto de clase Row, porque un Row es un indexer, no es texto.  Que pasa si usa dt.Rows["FechaIngreso"][0] ?

Comment: Como dice Duston, no puedes hacer eso, tendrias que hacer algo así: lblFechaIngreso.Text = dt.Rows[0]["FechaIngreso"].ToString(); Por una parte, debes indicar que Numero de Row quieres usar, y segundo, convertir el valor a texto, ya que quieres llenar la propiedad Text

Comment: Deberías colocar el error que recibes, de inicio se me ocurre compares el nombre del campo de tu tabla debe ser el mismo nombre, MAY/MIN "Verificalo".

Comment: @Lizeth por favor agrega también el resultado de ese select